# C code compiles only when I include .c file

Tags: c, struct

When I try to compile the code it works only when I include the Object.c in Dictionary.c. As part of my H.W I cant change Dictionary.h and main and can't declare structs in .h file. Can you please suggest a fix?

**object.h**

```
#ifndef __OBJECT_H
#define __OBJECT_H

typedef struct Object Object;

Object createObject (int key, int value);

int getKey (Object object);
int getValue (Object object);
int isSmaller (Object x, Object y);

#endif
```

**object.c:**

```
#include "object.h"

struct Object 
{
    int key;
    int value;
};

Object createObject (int key, int value)
{
    Object object = {key,value};
    return object;
}

int getKey (Object object)
{
    return object.key;
}

int getValue (Object object)
{
    return object.value;
}

int isSmaller (Object x, Object y)
{
    if (x.key < y.key)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

**dictionary.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "object.h"
#include "object.c"
#include "dictionary.h"

struct Dictionary
{
    Object* array;
    int sizeOfArray;
    int numOfObjects;
};
```

Comment: What does your compile command look like?

Comment: Also, _"I [...] can't declare structs in .h file"_ - why is that? Does the assignment dictate that?

Comment: Header files need not be ".h" (that's a useful convention). Try renaming "object.h" to, say, "object.include", add the definition of the structure there, and `#include "object.include"`, ... but don't tell anyone I suggested this :)

Comment: regarding: `#ifndef __OBJECT_H
#define __OBJECT_H`    double leading underscores and/or a leading underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for the environment.  I.E.  Do NOT incorporate leading underscores

Comment: regarding: `#include "dictionary.h"`  The header file is not posted in the OPs question (and is actually not needed.)

Answer (score 4):

You can't declare a variable or field as a struct without having the defined the struct first. That's because the compiler needs to know its size (and the offsets of the fields, if you use those), and that requires the definition.

However, declaring pointers to a struct that hasn't been defined is perfectly fine since the compiler knows the size of a pointer. So when having an opaque type is desireable, one might use an interface based around pointers to the struct as this avoids the need to define the struct in the header file.

For example,

`object.h`:

```c
#ifndef __OBJECT_H
#define __OBJECT_H

typedef struct Object Object;

Object* Object_new(int key, int val);
void Object_delete(Object* object);

int Object_get_key(const Object* object);
int Object_get_val(const Object* object);

int Object_is_smaller(const Object* x, const Object* y);

#endif
```

`object.c`:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "object.h"

struct Object {
    int key;
    int val;
};

Object* Object_new(int key, int val) {
    Object* object = malloc(sizeof(Object));
    if (!object)
        return NULL;

    object->key = key;
    object->val = val;
    return object;
}

void Object_delete(Object* object) {
    free(object);
}

int Object_get_key(const Object* object) { return object->key; }
int Object_get_val(const Object* object) { return object->val; }

int Object_is_smaller(const Object* x, const Object* y) { return x->key < y->key; }
```

An example user:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "object.h"

int main(void) {
    Object* object = Object_new(4, 5);
    printf("%d: %d\n",
        Object_get_key(object),
        Object_get_val(object)
    );

    Object_delete(object);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> can't declare structs in .h file

Why? .h files are **the proper** place for defining structures which will be used by several .c files!

---

Move the type definition to object.h

```
#ifndef __OBJECT_H
#define __OBJECT_H

typedef struct Object Object;

// type definition in header file
struct Object 
{
    int key;
    int value;
};

Object createObject (int key, int value);

int getKey (Object object);
int getValue (Object object);
int isSmaller (Object x, Object y);

#endif
```

Comment: I'd agree but OP specifically said that they _"can't declare structs in .h file"_ (the reason for that we don't know, however).

Comment: You're right @domsson. I'm tempted to delete my answer :)

Comment: I'd wait for OP to clarify. Maybe his comment only referred to the `Dictionary.h`, I'm not quite sure.